# Android App showing blank screen after repeated launch and exit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am writing an activity which gets launched from another activity. The new activity which gets launched sometimes shows blank screen if repeatedly exiting and re-launching the screen

Following the the onCreate() of the activity which is getting launched from another activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String intentAction = intent.getAction(); 
        if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                Log.w("onCreate()", "Main Activity is not the root.  Finishing Main Activity instead of launching.");
            finish();
            return;       
        }
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("onCreate()", "Calling setContentView()");
    setContentView(R.layout.dial_screen);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.duration);
    mute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mute);
    end = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.end); 

}
```

And the here is dial_screen.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/bg1024_600"
tools:context="com.harman.contacts.CallScreenActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/number"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/dialling"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/mute"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:text="@string/mute"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/end"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/end_call"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Everytime I am getting the Log before setContentView()(which means the activity is getting launched properly) but sometimes, even after getting the log, the layout is not being shown.
The blank screen is not coming everytime, but sometimes. Any idea why this is and how to fix it ? Also let me know if further information is required.

Comment: Kindly let me know why the '-1'. I have searched enough on the net before posting the question. Similar bug has been observed in Android default call app also. However after searching a lot I couldn't find anything. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I get something like this too. On pressing back to exit, I get a blank black screen for sometime. I have to keep pressing back repeatedly for the app to totally exit :-(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("onCreate()", "Calling setContentView()");
    setContentView(R.layout.dial_screen);
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String intentAction = intent.getAction(); 
        if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                Log.w("onCreate()", "Main Activity is not the root.  Finishing Main Activity instead of launching.");
            finish();
            return;       
        }
    }

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.duration);
    mute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mute);
    end = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.end); 

}
```

Comment: This did not help. Still, occasionally I am getting a blank screen after continuously pressing back key and relaunching the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what is wrong, but as I observed that this issue is not happening when I press the home key, I found a work-around. I made the behaviour of return key same as back-key by implementing `onBackPressed()` . Hope this hack helps someone facing similar issue :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

This is not the solution but a simple work around. I will keep this question open for some days for someone to come up with actual solution